# The Laplacian of a tubular neighborhood

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g_M)$ be a compact submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Are there any known results relating the spectrum of the Laplace-Beltrami operator of M to the spectrum of the  Laplace-Beltrami operator of a $\varepsilon$-tubular neighborhood of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: For clarification: when talking about the Laplace-Beltrami operator of a tubular neighborhood, are you thinking of the neighborhood as a manifold with boundary? With Neumann boundary conditions?

Comment: If $M$ is closed, then the tubular neighborhood is isometric to $M\times\mbox{ a disk}$ and you can separate variables. If $M$ has boundary, then I imagine you can compare the spectrum of the tubular neighborhood to the spectrum of $M\times\mbox{ a disk}$ by using test functions constructed from eigenfunctions of $M$ and sines/cosines.

Comment: There are papers by S. Teufel et al. about "quantum wave guides". A.f.a.i.k., they consider Schrödinger operators with a potential that is large outside such a  tubular neighbourhood. Then they show that the small eigenvalues of the full operator can be approximated nicely by an "effective operator" on a bundle over the submanifold. I have not followed their work, but it might include operators of the type you describe by now.